# Why is the browser satisfied with a response without content-length

Tags: sockets, http, browser

Usually when I send a response to the browser I have to enter content-length in the http headers, otherwise the browser never stops loading (wait for more data)

But recently, I tested rust code:

```
let response = format!("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n{}", contents);
stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
```

The browser receives this without any problems, stops loading after receiving the response.(even though content-length is not specified in the response)

Can someone pls explain this?... What makes the browser satisfied with the response in this scenario (even though it does not contain: Content-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content-length` is optional as long as the connection is closed after the response is done. From [RFC 7230 section 3.3.3 Message Body Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3):

> 7. Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message
>    body length, so the message body length is **determined by the
>    number of octets received prior to the server closing the
>    connection**.

Comment: If this is HTTP/1.1, the response likely uses "chunked" encoding, in which case no Content-Length header field is needed. In HTTP/2 it is never needed.

Comment: @JulianReschke: The response sent by the server is clearly shown in the question. If it would use chunked encoding there would need to be a header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` - which is not there.